# Chunk will not render in quarto, but executes fine

Tags: rendering, quarto

I hope someone can help me solve an issue in Quarto. I am trying to render a pdf, the code works fine in R, also the chunk I have issues with executes fine in Quarto, but when I render it, it halts with this message:

```
processing file: DSS.qmd |.......................................... | 83% (unnamed-chunk-26)Quitting from lines 368-448 (DSS.qmd) Error in [.data.frame(all, , 51:55) : undefined columns selected Calls: .main ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> alpha -> [ -> [.data.frame Execution halted
```

It is saying that these columns don't exist..they do, and the code works fine both in R and in Quarto itself, just won't work when rendering.I've checked the data file, and it contains the mentioned columns.Everything works fine in R, and also in Quarto if I just execute the chunk. The results are produced. Only when I try rendering it halts it with this message.

I would really appreciate your help in case you've encountered a similar issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can replicate what you are trying to render. 

Also try to follow these general recommendations [here](https://quarto.org/docs/troubleshooting/)